# Switching rows and columns in pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm new to Python and after a lot of tinkering, have managed to clean up some .csv data.

I now have a bunch of countries as rows and a bunch of dates as columns, and am trying to create a chart showing a line for each country's value over time.

The problem is that when I enter df.plot() it results in a chart with each date as a line.

I have melted the data such that the first column is country, second is date, and third is value, but all I get is a single blue block growing over time (not multiple lines). How can I fix this?

Comment: You would strongly benefit from providing a [mcve] here to let people understand the issue and possibly provide a solution.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please show us some data and code that show your problem. Read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `transpose` function in `[pandas][1]`:

Or instead of `df.plot`, you can use `plot(coloumn, row)`.

As it was mentioned in comments, it is always better to provide an example (look at @importanceofbeingeenest comment).